# Possible $x$ values for a parametric equation

Tags: calculus, parametric

$x=\sin t $ and $y=3\cos 2t$ over the interval $-\pi/2 \leq t \leq \pi/2$.

I know how to eliminate $t$, but I was asked to determine the possible $x$ values for the parametric equation and the Cartesian equation. I do not understand what the question is asking (indicate the portion of the graph traced by the particle). Am I supposed to plug all the values in the interval and see what values $x$ are the same?

Comment: Hint: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%7Bx+%3D+sin%28t%29%2C+y+%3D+3+cos%282t%29%7D%2C+-pi%2F2+%3C%3D+t+%3C%3D+pi%2F2. Now, how do you find the Cartesian equation (you said you know how to do this)?

Comment: I eliminated $t$ by using the trig identity $cos^2t + sin^2t = 1$, I got $y=-6x^2 + 3$. I have trouble identifying the possible x values for the parametric equation and cartesian equation.

Comment: @StevenN: You have a $\cos 2t$ term, so how did you use that?

Comment: Oops, I meant that I used $cos(2t) = 1+2sin^2(t)$, I had a long day :(.

Comment: @StevenN: OK. That's right. But $\cos(2t)=1-2\sin^2(t)$ I believe. You find something like $y=3(1-2x^2)$, right? Do you see that the graph of this curve is larger than the graph you get by that parametrization? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Umm the question is asking me to indicate the path of the curve that is being traced by the particle. (which part of the parametric graph is in the domain).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the point is this:

If you eliminate $t$, you'll get some implicit equation $f(x,y) = 0$. This equation defines a set $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : f(x,y) = 0\}$.

The parametric equations generate another set $B = \{ (\sin t, 3\cos 2t) : -\pi/2 \le t \le \pi/2\}$.

The point of the exercise is to see that the sets $A$ and $B$ are not the the same. In fact $B$ is a proper subset of $A$. Saying it another way, the given paramerization does not "cover" the entire curve. Looking at the possible range of $x$ values generated by the parametric equations is one way to see this.

Specifically, $\sin t \le 1$ for $-\pi/2 \le t \le \pi/2$, so the parametric equations will only generate points $(x,y)$ with $x \le 1$ -- the moving particle never travels to the right of the vertical line $x = 1$. The point set $A$ described by the implicit equation does not have this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's unclear what you want, I'd just guess what you are looking for.

If $-\pi/2 \leq t \leq \pi/2$ then $\sin^{-1}$ is defined and you can find $t$ by taking inverses:

$$ t= \sin^{-1}(x)$$
Now, plugging in $t$ you'll get:

$y=3\cos(2\sin^{-1}(x))=3((\cos(\sin^{-1}(x)))^2-(\sin(\sin^{-1}(x)))^2)$

$$y=3((\cos(\sin^{-1}(x))^2-x^2)=3((\sqrt{1-x^2} )^2-x^2)=3(1-2x^2)$$

You can also get this by using the trig identity $\cos(2t)=1-2\sin^2(t)$.

Now, notice that $ |x=\sin(t)| \leq 1$, therefore

$|x|^2 \leq 1 \implies |x^2| \leq 1 \implies 0 \leq x^2 \leq 1 $

$ \implies -2 \leq -2x^2 \leq 0 \implies -1 \leq 1-2x^2 \leq 1$

$ \implies -3 \leq 3(1-2x^2) \leq 3 \implies -3 \leq y \leq 3 \implies |y| \leq 3$

Notice that $\sin(t)$ is continuous and it does get equal to $-1$ and $1$ at $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ respectively. So, your parametrization only covers the part of the curve that lies inside the rectangle $(-1,1) \times (-3,3)$.